# Search if "," present in a dataframe column and split it into 2 dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

Need to search "," in the  dataframe column. Once found split the column into 2 dataframe columns.

```
Value
=====
59.5

59.5, 5

60

60,5
```

desired output below:

```
value1  value2

======  ======

59.5

59.5      5

60        

60        5
```

Tried the below code:

```
df['value1'], df_merge['value2'] = df['value'].str.split(',', 1).str

df['value1'], _, df_merge['value2'] = str(df['value']).partition(',')
```

None of them helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
 df= df['Value'].str.split('\,', expand=True).rename(columns={0:'A',1:'B'})

      A     B
0  59.5  None
1  59.5     5
2    60  None
3    60     5
```

If you wanted to mantain other columns as per your comments below, use the following code;

```
df=df.join(df['Value'].str.split('\,', expand=True).rename(columns={0:'A',1:'B'}))



    Value     A     B
0    59.5  59.5  None
1  59.5,5  59.5     5
2      60    60  None
3    60,5    60     5
```

Comment: Tried the above code. But after assigning i am having only the A column, i am loosing all other columns in my dataframe. My code: df_merge= df_merge['PDH_Value'].str.split('\,', expand=True).rename(columns={0:'pdh_age',1:'pdh_service'})

Comment: Try `df=df.join(df['Value'].str.split('\,', expand=True).rename(columns={0:'A',1:'B'}))`

Comment: Now the last B column alone is missing. Rest all columns are displaying.

Comment: df_merge= df_merge.join(df_merge['PDH_Value'].str.split('\,', expand=True).rename(columns={0:'pdh_age',1:'pdh_service'}))                                                      Missing the pdh_service column. Pls chk.

Comment: Cant reproduce your issue with the data you gave.join uses index, because no alteration happens on the index during the split process, no data should be lost. Does also not make sense 1 column gets appended and the other doesnt. issue is somewhere in your data. Code should work. You can try using the code provided by @SeaBean also.

Answer (score 0):

To expand into existing dataframe, simply use:

```
df[['Value1', 'Value2']] = df['Value'].str.split(',', expand=True)
```

Result:

```
     Value Value1 Value2
0     59.5   59.5   None
1  59.5, 5   59.5      5
2       60     60   None
3    60, 5     60      5
```